# $f(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial with $f(0)\neq 0$ and $f(f(x)+x)=f(x)(x^2+4x-7)$

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, functional-equations

> $f(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial with $f(0) \neq 0$ and $$f(f(x)+x)=f(x)(x^2+4x-7)$$
>
> It is given that the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $(x-1)$ is $3$.
>
> Find the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by$(x-3)$.

---

My Attempt:

Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $a,c \neq 0 $

I got $a+b+c=3$

And by the functional equation

$a[ax^2+(b+1)x+c]^2+b[ax^2+(b+1)x+c]+c= [ax^2+bx+c][x^2+4x-7]$

Then by putting $x=0$ , $ac^2 +bc+c=-7c$

Since $c \neq 0 $ , we have $ac+b+8=0$

Then comparing the coeffiecient of $x^4$ , we get $a^3=a$

Since $a \neq 0$ , $a=-1 $ or $a =1 $

Then how to proceed with two values of $a$ ?

or Is there a polynomial satisfying these conditions?

Comment: I updated my answer to give a full, simple proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if $F$ is a field, whose algebraic closure is $\bar{F}$, and $q(X)\in F[X]$ is a polynomial of degree $2$ with leading coefficient $k\neq 0$, then all solutions to $$f\big(\alpha\,f(X)+X\big)=f(X)\,q(X)\,,\tag{*}$$ where $\alpha\neq 0$ is a fixed element of $F$ and $f(X)\in \bar{F}[X]$, are given by $$f(X)=0\,,$$ $$f(X)=+\frac{1}{\alpha\sqrt{k}}\,q\left(X-\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)\,,$$ and $$f(X)=-\frac{1}{\alpha\sqrt{k}}\,q\left(X+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)\,,$$ where $\sqrt{k}$ is one of the square roots of $k$.  Thus, if $X^2-k$ is irreducible in $F[X]$, then the only solution to (*) in $F[X]$ is $f(X)=0$.

> **Hint:**  It is easy to see that nonconstant solutions to (*) must be of degree $2$.  Suppose that $$q(X)=k\,(X-u)(X-v)\,,$$ where $u,v\in\bar{F}$.  Then, it follows immediately that $$f(X)=\pm \frac{\sqrt{k}}{\alpha}\,(X-p)(X-q)$$ for some $p,q\in\bar{F}$.  Compute $$\frac{f\big(\alpha\, f(X)+X\big)}{k\,f(X)}$$ in terms of $X,p,q,\sqrt{k},\alpha$.  This should be the same as $$\frac{q(X)}{k}=(X-u)(X-v)\,.$$

In particular, if $F=\mathbb{C}$, $q(X)=X^2+4\,X-7$ (so that $k=1$), and $\alpha=1$, then the nonzero solutions to the functional equation (*) are $$f(X)=+q(X-1)=+X^2+2\,X-10$$ and $$f(X)=-q(X+1)=-X^2-6\,X+2\,.$$  Note that the extra condition that $f(1)=3$ is incompatible with all such polynomials, whence there are no solutions to the OP's conditions.

Comment: But you need to *prove* your claim if you want to use that general result to solve this simple special case.

Comment: I left it as an exercise for the OP.  If you want to prove it, then be my guest.

Comment: Did you prove it, or do you have a link to a proof?

Comment: No, I don't think there is a link to a proof.  I devised this generalization on my own about 45 minutes ago.  If requested, I can write a proof here .  But I would rather that the OP works this out on his own.

Comment: I think you should at least give the OP some hints, since it may be beyond what was expected for an exercise like this.

Comment: A hint is added in the hidden portion.

Comment: The hint should help many readers. I added an alternative proof, and I added a (well-deserved) upvote.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint** $\ $ Much easier: the functional equation allows you to generate further values of $f(x),\,$ e.g. $\,\color{#c00}{f(1)} = 3\,\Rightarrow f(4) = f(\color{#c00}{f(1)}\!+\!1) = \ldots\,$ Then we can easily compute $\,f(x)\,$ by interpolation.

**Remark** $ $ It turns out that the interpolated polynomial does not satisfy the functional equation, therefore no solution exists (probably there is a typo in the statement). $ $

Alternative proof: $ $ for any polynomial $\,f(x)\,$ it is true that $\,f(x)\mid f(x\!+\!f(x))\,$ because $\,{\rm mod}\ f(x)\!:\ f(x\!+\!f(x))\equiv f(x)\equiv 0.\,$ When $\,f\,$ is quadratic the cofactor (quotient) $\,g\,$ has a simple closed form, which can be computed directly or, more simply, by the Lemma below.

Therefore, by the Lemma, if  $\,g(x)  = af(x\!+\!1/a) = x^2\!+\!4x\!-\!7\,$ then the lead coeff $\,a^2=1,\,$ thus if $\,a=1\,$ then $\,g(x) = f(x\!+\!1)\,$ so $\,f(1)=g(0)=-7\neq 3,\,$ and if $\,a=-1\,$ this yields $\,g(x)= -f(x\!-\!1),\,$ so $\,f(1)=-g(2) = -5\neq 3.\,$ Though unneeded, going further we get $\,f(x) = g(x\!-\!1)= x^2\!+\!2x\!-\!10\,$ if $\,a=1,\,$  $\,f(x) = -g(x\!+\!1) = -x^2\!-\!6x\!+\!2\,$ if $\,a=-1.\,$

**Lemma** $\,\ f(x\!+\!f(x))\, =\, a\,f(x)f(x\!+\!1/a)\ $ if $\ f(x) = a(x\!-\!r)(x\!-\!r')$

$\!\begin{align}{\bf Proof}\quad  f(x\!+\!f(x))\, &=\, a\,(x\!+\!f(x)\!-\!r)\ (x\!+\!f(x)\!-\!r')\\[.1em]  
&=\, a\,a(x\!-\!r)(1/a\!+\!x\!-\!r')\  a(x\!-\!r')(1/a\!+\!x\!-\!r)\\[.1em] 
&=\, af(x)\,f(1/a\!+\!x)\end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

$ac + b + 8=0$, $ac - a - c + 11 = 0$. If $a = 1$, then $10 = 0$. So $a = -1$, hence $c = 6$, $b = -2$, $f(x) = -x^2 -2x + 6$

Comment: okay! But does $f(x)=-x^2-2x+6$ satisfy the functional eq ?

Comment: Can you show me the steps please. Thank you

Comment: No it does not satisfy

Comment: It is early, and my head is not functioning right. So a mistake is even more likely than usual. Putting $x=1$ in the functional equation, we get $f(4)=f(1)(-2)=-6$.  This does not match the answer obtained, which may mean the bits of information we were given are incompatible.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I didn't actually check it; I just multiplied a few terms in my head and it seemed to work, but I should have simply substituted some values. Anyway, I can neither spot a mistake in the OP's work nor in mine, so yes, it seems that the information are incompatible

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think so.

Comment: @Kelenner If there is no such polynomial , then how to prove that ?

Comment: @AngeloMark: The calculations have already been done, the only thing to check is that they are correct. One calculation shows that $a\ne 1$. Another calculation shows that $a=1$.  Contradiction.

Comment: Well I have deleted my comment as André Nicolas 's comment was almost the same. With $f(1)=3$.  $f(4)=-6$,  $f(-2)=-6\times 25$. I have found that $a=-9$, $b=42$, $c=-30$. Of course, as we have $a^2=1$, this is not possible.If my computation are correct, this prove that the polynomial does not exists.
\

Answer (score 1):

My answer to the question : [Quadratic Functional equations.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1856052/quadratic-functional-equations/1856084#1856084)

Should work in the exact same manner, the extra conditions may or may not contradict the solution obtained, but in the case of a contradiction, then such a function does not exist.